# Adding GridView in Fragment

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

Here is my code for getting GridView:

```
public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {


AppController instance = AppController.getInstance();
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
String html;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);

    GridView gridView;
        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.layout.fragment_movies);
        movies = getMoviesList();
        gridView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(getActivity(), movies));

    return rootView;
}

public List<Movie> getMoviesList()
{
    List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();

    try {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(getActivity().getAssets().open("site.html"), "UTF-8", "");
        Elements get = doc.select("div.post.lit > h2");
        for (Element element : get) 
        {
            movies.add(new Movie(element.text()));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    System.out.println(movies.size());

    return movies;
}


}
```

and here is my `MovieAdapter` class for items in gridView:

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie>
{


List<Movie> moviesList;
Context context;

public MoviesAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> objects) 
{
    super(context, android.R.id.content, objects);
    this.moviesList = objects;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies_individual, parent);
    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    name.setText(moviesList.get(position).getName());
    description.setText(moviesList.get(position).getDescription());
    return view;
}
}
```

when I run the app, it just keep crashing and throwing `NullPointerException` in the line of setting adapter for gridView.(`gridView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(getActivity(), movies));`
I checked movieList items and it's populated properly.

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is here:

```
gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.layout.fragment_movies);
```

You need to provide grid's id as the `findViewById(int)` argument. Now you're providing the layout's id, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49957819/gridview-and-it-is-images-are-not-automatically-fit-for-all-the-screen-sizes-in